# Using jQuery, how to specify with the `.attr` method, the second of two html classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using jQuery and are using the .attr method as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class1').click(function(){
        id = $(this).attr('.class2'); 
    });
});
```

Say I have the following HTML for the above function:

```
<div class="class1 $class2"></div>
```

The second class is attributed at runtime, so I have 10 divs, each with `class1`, but several with `class2`. Then I wish to use the jQuery function at the top, so that whenever I click on any of the divs, it applies the specific `class2` of that div, to the variable `ID`.

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: You're trying to do what exactly?

Comment: `$('class1')` selects elements with the tag name `class1`. HTML defines no such element. Please don't tell me this is your code and you really have `<class1 ...>` in your HTML.

Comment: @JanDvorak - According to the code, the element would look like `<class1 class2="something"></class1>`, now that's strange ?

Comment: This isn't in my code, I was writing this for an example. Sorry I readjusted the code. I'll add some more info in a moment.

Comment: `attr()` gets an attribute, not a class?

Comment: If your HTML is like `<a class="a" class="b">` that's invalid HTML, and you can't obtain both values. `<a class1="a" class2="b">` is still invalid HTML (and these attributes bear no relation to the `class` attribute anyways). If your HTML is `<a class="a b">`, then you can fetch the attribute and split by space. Again, what are you trying to do? Are you looking for `$().hasClass` or (say) `$().is`?

Comment: @adeneo not after his latest update. Now it's `<something class="class1" .class2="something">`

Comment: k4kuz, with your presented code changing this fast,  how can we trust you _anything_ we've seen so far even _resembles_ your real code?

Comment: @JanDvorak I've just updated my code I hope it makes more sense. On a practical level, I want to click on any of 10 divs, and have a variable change to the second class of said div. The divs all have a different class2, so to speak.

Comment: check my (@user2727841) answer and its link...

Comment: @k4kuz0 maybe you should be using data-attributes instead? `<div class="class1" data-something="value">`

Comment: @JanDvorak My presented code isn't "changing so fast" I changed it once because I received several comments saying it made no sense. I have a lot of code that is linked to this problem and didn't want to saturate this whole page with half of my code. I was trying to be concise but I guess I failed in that. You don't have to "trust" me at all, "trust" the fact that I am searching for help, and therefore wouldn't deceive people I'm trying to elicit help from.

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();` ??????????????

Comment: @JanDvorak Hmm you could be right, I haven't used data-attributes before. I will take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `class2` comes from your PHP code, you seem to hit the usecase of data-attributes.

With data-attributes you can easily have some extra data (often used for javascript purposes) on your HTML elements without having to use special classes or ids for that.

It works like that:

```
<span data-hero="batman">I'm a Bat!</span>
```

Where in your Javascript (using jQuery) you get the value of it by simply doing:

```
$('span').data('hero');
```

Refer to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for further information.

Comment: This is perfect, and I think it is the exact thing I'm looking for. I am very new to coding and didn't know Data-attributes existed before now. "easily have some extra data (often used for javascript purposes) on your HTML elements without having to use special classes or ids for that." hits the nail on the head, cheers!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer, so others will see :).

Comment: I will do so when it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.class1').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('class').replace('class1','').trim();
    });
});
```

Comment: My userscript adds a third class to the HTML. Perfectly legitimate operation. Now `dynamicClass` reads "class2 foreign-class". Of course, user's own code could add a new class just as easily.

Comment: ah yes, with more than 1 class this is extremely brittle code. data-attributes are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi class tag this mean the HTML code would be like this:

```
<sometag class="class1 class2">...</sometag>
```

I think the simplest approach is to do some string operations on the `class` attribute of the tag:

```
var class2 = $(selector).attr("class").split(" ")[1];
```

OR you can write a simple jQuery plugin to do the work for you:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.secondClass = function(){
        var c = this.attr("class").split(" ");
                    if(c.length >= 2)
                        return c[1];
    };
}(jQuery))
```

Usage: `var class2 = $(selector).secondClass();`

Hope this helps.